# Windows 10 machine randomly reboots with Hyper-V on

Tags: windows-10, hyper-v

I just upgraded Windows 10 to 2004 version, which went well, and then got my machine randomly reboot while working. No error message, nothing in the even viewer, just sudden reboots that happen regularly. I could have been clueless here, but fortunately the same happened to me some weeks ago when I turned on Hyper-V in order to play with Docker. At that time, my only solution was to turn off Hyper-V like so:

```
bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off
```

and to forget about playing with docker.

I'm puzzled by what can cause this issue and I don't know what to try.
My PC is equipped with an Asus Z170-A and an i7-6700K. No overclocking. GPU is GTX 1060. Virtualization is enabled in bios.

**Update 1**: all Asus drivers are current. Bios is not, but no mention of virtualization in changelogs.

**Update 2**: ran the dism.exe commands proposed by John. There were no error messages. Let the pc unattended. It had rebooted when I came back half an hour later. Note that I have not yet updated my bios. I am always frightened to do so as I don't want to get a bricked PC or get all bios settings reset...

Comment: Have you got Hardware Virtualization (VT-x) enable in BIOS?  Update BIOS, and then all Drivers with the ASUS Driver Update App.

Comment: VT-x is enabled, otherwise I could not run docker. BIOS is not the latest one since I avoid  that when not needed. The changelog for the newer versions do not indicated something special about virtualization. I can check for other drivers.

Comment: Virtualization (for my machines given VT-x enabled) is automatic. Nothing special for virtualization settings.  So do check for Driver updates and also check for Windows Updates (run manually to check).

Comment: As said, all drivers were already current. Windows update was fine as of yesterday since I just upgraded to 2004.

Comment: Try the following (more difficult now).  From an Admin Command Prompt:  (1) dism.exe  /online  /cleanup-image  /StartComponentCleanup   then   (2)  dism.exe  /online  /cleanup-image  /restorehealth  then  (3)  SFC /SCANNOW  .  When done, restart and test.

Comment: Done that and unfortunately it rebooted again after a few minutes unattended. Note that I have not updated my bios since I am always fearful to do so.

Comment: You can try a Repair Install from the Microsoft Media Creation Link, but also be ready to back up and reinstall Windows. If you do, add software slowly to see if there is offending software.

Comment: @John, unfortunately this is where I'll have to stop because this is my main dev PC and I have no time for these next steps. But thanks for your help.